# robotium - clicking on action bar tabs

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, robotium

I'm finishing up moving to the actionbar (using actionbarsherlock), and one of the last things is to convert all the robotium integration tests. Clicking on action bar action items seems to be solved, however I cannot figure out how to click on action bar tabs with Robotium.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Action Bar Screen]

you can use

```
[1] solo.clickOnText("TAB A"); 
    // click on action bar tab 1
    // where action bar tab 1 diaplay text = "TAB A"

[2] solo.clickOnText("TAB A"); 
    // click on action bar tab 1
    // where action bar tab 1 diaplay text = "TAB A"
```

if you have images in action bar tabs,

[image]

```
[1] solo.clickOnImage(0); OR solo.clickOnImageButton(0);
        // click on action bar tab 1

[2] solo.clickOnImage(1); OR solo.clickOnImageButton(1); 
        // click on action bar tab 2
```

i hope this will help you. Thanks.

Comment: This approach does not work sometimes in my project, where I use the actionbarsherlock. If I run the Robotium test on a older Android version device, where the .abs actually kicks in, then Robotium is unable to click on the tabs by their texts. No problem on ICS and later

Comment: As far as I saw Android 4.0 works with the Strings as you specified them in the navigation tab, potentially containing lower case letters. Android 2.3.3. for instance requires upper case Strings ... :)

Answer (score 2):

Click on action bar :-If you have the source code of the application under test, The best way is when you identify the Action Bar Item by its Id, which can be found in the R.Java of the application under test.

solo.clickOnActionBarItem(R.id.ItemToBEClicked);